# Pseudo-Code for linear recursion of a Tetranacci number

Tags: algorithms

In my class we have to write a pseudo code in java for two types of recursive methods for Tetranacci numbers (similar to Fibonacci except with 4 numbers). We have to write it in exponential form and in linear form. I have figured out the exponential form, although I'm struggling with how to make in linear. We have to test it with the value 5,10 the values should return 2,56. My code for exponential is:

> int exponentialTet(int n){
>
> if(n==0 || n==1 || n==2){
>
> return 0;
>
> else if(n==3)
>
> return 1;
>
> else return (exponentialTet(n-1) + exponentialTet(n-2) + exponentialTet(n-3) +
> exponentialTet(n-4))

Comment: That seems more like the linear solution to me since you are doing $T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-2} + T_{n-3} + T_{n-4}$ which is a linear combination of the terms. I would an exponential form to involve exponential functions like $T_n = 2^n + 3^{n+1}$ (randomly made up).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is implementing (not very efficiently) the linear recursion.  For the exponential form, you should not have any recursion.  The comparable thing for Fibonacci is [Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).  To do this, you need the roots of the characteristic polynomial $x^4=x^3+x^2+x+1$  The use of these is explained somewhat [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence#Solving)

Comment: both exponential forms and linear forms are just exercises we have to do. The exponential form doesnt have to be recursive i know but it's just for practice. But i just cant figure out how the to get the method to work linearly.

Comment: If $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$ are the roots of the polynomial, the exponential form is $T_n=a_1r_1^n+a_2r_2^n+a_3r_3^n+a_4r_4^n$  You need to find the $a$'s and $r$'s

Comment: The [exact expressions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4%3Dx%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B1) for the roots are a **mess**

Answer (score 0):

You are *not* implementing linear-recursion (as Ross Millikan has claimed), you are implementing what is known as *multiple-recursion*. In order to implement the linear version of this algorithm, your base case should pass the first four values [1, 0, 0, 0], and every recursive returns should pass a manipulated array. Check my code:

```
    public static int[] tetranacci_linear(int n)
        {
        int[] A = new int[4];
        int sum;

        // Tetranacci is pre-defined before this point
        if (n<=3) // BASE CASE
        {
            // Stores the last 4 fib numbers [k, k-1, k-2, k-3] where k is the current Tet. number
            A[0] = 1;
            A[1] = 0;
            A[2] = 0;
            A[3] = 0;
            return A;
        }
        else
        {
            // Recursive case
            A = tetranacci_linear(n - 1);
            sum = A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3];
            A[3] = A[2];
            A[2] = A[1];
            A[1] = A[0];
            A[0] = sum;
            return A;
        }

    }
```

Comment: As I understand the question, this is the intended answer.  I'd take one more step and use tail recursion.

Comment: Can you comment on how you would apply tail recursion to this implementation?

Comment: Not sure how to post legible code in a comment.  I'll temporarily add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tail-recursive implementation, otherwise similar to the one by @Anthony.

```
  private static int tetranacci(int n) {
    if (n < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative argument.");
    int[] A = {0, 0, 0, 1};
    return _tetranacci(n, A);
  }

  private static int _tetranacci(int n, int[] A) {
    if (n < 4) return A[n];
    int sum = A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) A[i] = A[i+1];
    A[3] = sum;
    return _tetranacci(n-1, A); 
  }
```